# Открытие диалог фрагмента в Clean Architecture

Tags: java, android, архитектура

Мне интересна работа с фрагментами и диалогФрагментами.
Вот я нашёл проект, но я смотрю его и у меня куча вопросов. Например, в Фрагменте слушатель нажатия на итем в списке (имею в виду onPhotoClick). И там это сделано без презентера. Так и должно быть?

https://github.com/dnsfrolov/BlackSplash/blob/da3a32e32cca08416df91fd200c6f0e981129fcf/app/src/main/java/com/dnsfrolov/unsplashapi/screen/home/HomeFragment.java

Comment: Код должен находиться в вопросе.

Comment: Тут спорный вопрос довольно. С одной стороны презентер должен обрабатывать пользовательский ввод, а с другой - чтобы его было проще тестировать, лучше не передавать в него context.
Я лично склоняюсь к тому, что работа с `Intent`'ами, всякие `Toast`/`Snackbar`, простые диалоги  - всё это лучше оставлять в `Activity`/`Fragment`

Answer (score 0):

Обычно в гайдах описывают академические примеры, где все идеально, но в реальности некоторыми правилами пренебрегают. Например, во вью валидацию сделают или, как в твоем примере, слушатель на клик без презентера. Бывают кейсы, где вью дергает презентер только для того, чтобы тот дернул вью в ответ, и никакой логики\альтернативных кейсов не предусмотрено. Опытные разработчики иногда выбирают ленивый путь, но чтобы не выстрелить себе в ногу нужно хорошо разбираться в теории, и понимать, где можно схитрить без последствий, а где нельзя. Как итог советую найти другой, академический пример и учится на нем. Как определить, что пример создан для обучения? Скорее всего у таких проектов есть инструкция\readme\home page с пояснениями.